# Client server communication in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am making a three page google web app. The first page will be login, second is user registration and third is application. I am stroing data from registration in a google sheet. Now I want the login from the first page in a manner in which script checks user id and password against the stored value of google sheet, but cluless how to implement it.

In Registration.html, i am collectibg user-id and password and storing it in googlesheet. I am able to do it without problem

For Login.html, I want to write a script which should check user-id and password input by an user against the values stored for that user-id in sheet For example, if user id stored in google sheet is 'g-user; and password is '123456' then while login if a user correctly enters these details then he would be redirected to application.html and if he enters it incorrectly then a message would be presented to him that "the user name/ password entered is wrong and he/she may retry"

I guess it can be done in following way,

Writing a function, say PwdCheck() in Code.gs, e.g.,

```
function PwdCheck(form){
/* collect form values entered in client login.html */
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Sheetid');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
  var UsrId = form.UsrId;
  var Pwd = form.Pwd; 
  var rr= sheet.getRange(2,3,100,2).getValues();
/* if clause has only one value from range specified by var rr, for example */
  if(UsrId == rr[0][0] && Pwd ==rr[0][1]){
     return Al();
  } else {

    return Msg();

  }


}

function Msg(){
  /* Code that present client(login.html) a message that password/userid are incorrect. retry again. This message can be presented in a <p> tage in login.html */
  return x;

}
function Al(){

  /* Code which redirects the login.html to application.html since password entered in login page are correct */

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop till you find entered username on stored spreadsheet, then get the password along with it. finally compare the client and server passwords.

```
function PwdCheck(form){
/* collect form values entered in client login.html */
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Sheetid');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
  var UsrId = form.UsrId;
  var Pwd = form.Pwd; 
  var storedPassword;
  var rr= sheet.getRange(2,3,100,2).getValues();

  //rr is an array you need to loop through the rows and find your user name, 
  //then pic the stored password for it
  for(var row in rr){
    if(UsrId == rr[row][0])
    {
      storedPassword = rr[row][1];
      break;
    }
  }

  // now check stord and entered password
  if( Pwd == storedPassword){
     return Al();
  } else {

    return Msg();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I need also the code for Msg() and Al() in particular becuase I am cluless about the code that needs to be written for these function in the problem stated in Question.

Comment: Well, that part is a different question.